# Keeping count inside a recursion?

Tags: c

I need to write a recursive function that prints out an English ruler's ticks.

Problem is I need to pass only one parameter, but I need the ruler to be (2^k)-1 ticks long (so for k=4, it'll print 15 ticks).

An example:

```
void printRuler(int k) {
    
    if (k == 0) {
        return;
    }

    if (k % 8 == 0) {
        printf("----");
    }
    else if (k % 4 == 0) {
        printf("---");
    }
    else if (k % 2 == 0) {
        printf("--");
    }
    else {
        printf("-");
    }
    printf("\n");

    drawRuler(k - 1);
}
```

My code obviously only prints out k ticks.

How do I keep track of how much I've printed inside a recursion?

Comment: Printing 2 ^ _k_ − 1 ticks suggests that your (linear) recursion isn't the right thing to do here. I think printing should look like the in-order traversal of a full binary tree of depth _k_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's approach this systematically. For the forst three *k*, your rulers look like this:

```
        1    ─                     2    ─                     3    ─
                                        ──                         ──
                                        ─                          ─
                                                                   ───
                                                                   ─
                                                                   ──
                                                                   ─
```

You can see a pattern here: Ruler *k* is a tick that's *k* units long with a ruler *k* − 1 on either side. If you tilt your head, it looks like a full binary tree.

So that's your recursion: Print a ruler for *k* − 1; print the centre tick; print another ruler for *k* − 1. In C:

```
void ruler(int k)
{
    if (k > 0) {
        ruler(k - 1);
        
        switch(k) {
        case 0:     break;
        case 1:     puts("-"); break;
        case 2:     puts("--"); break;
        case 3:     puts("---"); break;
        default:    puts("----"); break;
        }
        
        ruler(k - 1);
    }
}
```

(Of course, a real ruler would begin and end with a long tick. But that would yield 2<sup>*k*</sup> + 1 ticks and would not be easy to accomplish with a nice recursion like the one above.)

Answer (score 0):

I updated the answer according to your concern.
currently your function is void, you should change your function to something like this:

```
int drawRuler(int k) {
     int count = 0;
     if(printing executed here) {
        count++;  
        //print
     }else if (printing executed here')
     {
       count++;
       //print
     }

   return count + drawRuler(k - 1);
}

int main() {
    int totalCountOfPrintings = drawRuler(k)
    print(totalCountOfPrintings);
}
```

Comment: I need the function to work on its own unfortunately

Comment: I changed the answer based on your tip dear.